# SELECT COUNT DISTINCT as columns

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql

I have a table like this in psql db
[image]

i want to query output like this :

[image]

each column is showing count of that filetype in a timestamp. 
What will be the query? Any help will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Shows us some work, try something. Hint: GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :

SELECT filetype,COUNT(filetype),time
FROM factbucketmetrics
WHERE operation = 'INSERT'
GROUP BY time,filetype;